# linear time-invariant system output question?

Tags: linear-systems

Subtract the output of a linear time-invariant system whose shock response is $h \left[ n \right] = \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^{n} \left( u \left[ n \right] - u \left[ n - 2 \right] \right)$, for input $x \left[ n \right] = u \left[ n \right] - u \left[ n - 3 \right]$, where $u \left[ n \right]$ is the step function.

Comment: Hi, welcome to DSP.SE! Please note that HW questions must be tagged as such and cannot be provided with complete step by step solutions. On that note, the output $y[n]$ of an LTI system with an impulse response $h[n]$ is simply: $x[n] \ast h[n]$. Also make sure to typeset you mathematical equations using Tex.